# Handle Media Player

Tags: android, android-activity, android-mediaplayer

I have created an application that has 2 activities A and B.
From activity A I have a button to call B, in that B I have MediaPlayer to play a song list. When I press back button to back to A, then I press the button to call B again. All of my information's gone but the last Media Player keep playing, when I try to play another song, both Media play as the same. My problem is I want to keep the music playing when I press back button to A, and then I go back to B from A and play other songs without create new Media or just continue the last activity using the last Media Player.

Answer (score 1):

check [State diagram](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#StateDiagram) of the MediaPlayer. That should answer your problem. Read the javadoc about how and when to stop the player.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you maintain a global MediaPlayer object in your Activity B.

```
public static final MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer():
```

In your activity B, whenever you make any change to the player just call

```
player.stop() or player.reset();
```

before starting the audio session.